# how to create a sheet in an existing excel file for output or destination file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a situation where the source file is an EXCEL with a sheet in it. I am looking to use the same excel file as a destination file where by creating a new sheet in the same excel file. In an attempt, to achieve this, I took excel destination, in its editor, I tried to use the NEW feature that is right beside the feature "Name of the Excel Sheet" and VS is throwing the following error, would anyone please help me understand the scenario. Thank you for giving me your valuable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You cannot read and write to same excel file simultaneously. Create an intermediate step (.CSV file or .xlsx file etc) and use that file as a source file to write to the preferred excel sheet.

Comment: Thank you, Gunawardana. Would you pls give a little more elaboration on it?

Comment: Create a step to read excel next step would be writing that to a csv next would be reading that csv and final would be writing to the excel. CSV is just a place holder for values

Comment: Can you please accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't understand the approach you are referring to, Amila. Hence, I decided to look into this later. But, thank you for efforts in helping me.